# Tweaking Hash#to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I've been struggling with this one the whole day. In my Rails 2.3.5 app, I had a bunch of custom code which allowed the following to happen:

```
>> strip_hash_keys_for_json({ "a" => 1 }).to_json
=> "{ a: 1 }"
```

So you see that string keys don't get quoted. It was implemented by creating a `String` descendant class that returned `self` from `to_json`, and all of the hash keys were wrapped in this class.

Today I've started upgrading the app to Rails 3, and it has stopped working, since the JSON-encoding stuff had been rewritten quite seriously.

As you may probably know, in Rails 3 creating a JSON representation of a hash involves two methods:

- `as_json` which determines what elements of the hash should be present in JSON
- `encode_json` which actually returns a string representation containing the JSON

I figured that I can change the way things happen by observing what `encode_json` does, and tweaking some methods that get called from there.

The problem is that these two methods don't get called at all. I've checked for every stupid mistake I could make in my investigations and I can see nothing wrong. Google is of no help too, so I turn to the SO fellows for assistance.

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

OK so I figured out that in order for these methods to work I have to use `ActiveSupport::JSON::encode` directly instead of `to_json`. This seems weird because
 I thought `{}.to_json` is handled by the `Object#to_json` method defined in that same `encoding.rb` file, which in turn calls `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self, options)`.

Now I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove the strip_hash_keys_for_json ?

I opened up a console and got:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > Rails::VERSION::STRING
 => "2.3.5"
ruby-1.8.7-p249 > { "a" => 1 }.to_json
 => "{\"a\":1}"
```

Comment: what you got is the standard behavior of `to_json`. however, my desired behavior is for it not to quote string keys. have I stated the question unclearly?

Comment: Valid JSON requires the string keys to be quoted.